# Ionic 3 push notification with payload

Tags: ionic-framework, notifications, push

I have integrated push in ionic app & it's working. I used push.rx.notification().subscribe() to listen for notification. It's working when app is foreground. But when app was not open, notification is received, push.rx.notification().subscribe() is not called. Here is my app.component.ts code:

```
this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
    return this.push.saveToken(t);
  }).then( (t: PushToken) => {
  }).catch( (err) => {
    console.log('Error Saving Token: ' , err);
  });

  this.push.rx.notification()
  .subscribe((msg: any) => {
//this block only executing when in foreground
    console.log('Push Mesg : ' + msg.title + ' ' + msg.text);
  });
```

I am sending push from Ionic dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside of rx block is called when you click on a notification.
That only occurs when the push is send using the ionic api (via dashboard or http request), but if you send a push using the native api (android/ios) doesn't work. The push notification appears but the rx.notification method is never called.

Comment: I already mentioned it. I am sending push from Ionic dashboard.